# Using variable as value in post to php/mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, variables

I get a random row from a mysql-server using php. I then display some information and would like to let the users give feedback on that specific row. However, I can't seem to transfer the ID correctly to the update.php. (No updating is happening on the server). Can somebody spot out my error?

Mysql-php getting a (ugly) random row:

```
$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
$dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, username, message, ttime, field1, field2 FROM field WHERE done = 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");  
$array = mysql_fetch_row($result);      

echo json_encode($array);
```

Then index.php:

```
<div id="output">
<div id="username">content</div>
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function () 
  {   $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'api.php',   
      data: "",           
      dataType: 'json',             
      success: function(data)       
      {
        var id = data[0];           
        var vname = data[1];         
        var message = data[2]; 
    var timestamp = data[3]; 

        $('#output').html(timestamp +message );   
         $('#username').html( vname );

      } 
    });

  }); 
  </script>

  <script>
  $(document).jkey('a',function() {
      $.post("update.php", { id: "id"} )
    });
</script>
```

Then in the update.php:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/connection.php'); ?>
<?php 
$id = $_POST['id'];
$sql = "UPDATE field SET field1 = field1 +1 WHERE id = '$id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

Comment: What produce the var_dump on $id?

Comment: I'd recommend cleaning up the code a bit, you mixed everything in one block and it makes it really hard to read and understand. If you want better chances at getting help at least post more code and seperate the PHP from the javascript (oh and finish that ajax call, missing brackets and all those dots doesn't help us figure out whether that's your syntax error or you decided to only paste a small snippet of it)

Comment: Nice SQL injection hole you've got there. Be a shame if someone drove a truck through it and parked all over your server.

Comment: You want to send the ID value that you got from the ajax call on page load (var id = date[0]) to the update.php call?

Comment: @MarcB - Care to explain (and help?)

Comment: He's referring to $id = $_POST['id']; You should protect yourself from mysql injection, for starters take a look at the mysql_real_escape_string function and read up on the subject. I highly recommend it.

Comment: @user977101: http://bobby-tables.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a global `_id` in a `script` tag, then :

```
  $.ajax({                                      
  url: 'api.php',          
  data: "",    
  dataType: 'json',             
  success: function(data)    
  {
    var id = data[0]; 
    _id = id;
    //...
```

and

```
<script>
  $(document).jkey('a',function() {
    $.post("update.php", { "id": _id} ) // <--- Look here
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $.post("update.php", { id: "id"} )
```

is sending the String`id` to the server as the id. You'll want to replace it with the actual variable that holds the id number based on which row the user selected, for example

```
  $.post("update.php", { id: rowIDNum} )
```

If you provide some information on how the user is selecting a row, I can provide more details on how to determine the value to put in rowIDNum.